# Where to learn the 'real' funding threshold for Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions Individual Fellowship final project selection

Tags: funding

Recently, I received the preliminary result for the MSCA-IF-2016 (Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions Individual Fellowship) application, and I learned that I am in the 'reserve list'. I wonder if there is a way to learn the updated funding threshold, which can help me make a better guess regarding my position in the 'reserve list'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently contacted my national contact point. They were able to inform me on the size of the reserve list and my position on that list.

Best

Answer (score 3):

You can find the results from your national contact point and you can also check the list of the results as provided from their [site](http://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/portal/doc/call/h2020/msca-if-2016/1757610-msca_if_2016_percentile_en.pdf).

In addition, according to their [blog](http://mariecurieactions.blogspot.com.cy/2016/01/if-2015-my-project-is-on-reserve-list.html) from last year:

"This may take up to one year until you are informed if your proposal will be still be funded or not. **Experience from recent years shows that no more than 5 proposals - but depending on the panel!** - might be funded from the reserve list. It is impossible to foresee or give a valid estimation about the chances for funding."